# Desynchronizing MonoBehavior's "Update" from the overall app or UI Toolkit graphic output rendering in Unity?

Tags: unity, rendering, efficiency, ui-toolkit

**Is it possible to desynchronize `Application.targetFrameRate` and Monobehavior's `Update()` from the graphics output rendering rate of a UI Document, Panel, Game Object holding it, or global Unity app?**

Let's say you have a UI Document on a game object. Let's say you are monitoring via custom code for when there is actually any change in the visual display that needs to take place.

Let's say you ABSOLUTELY KNOW NOTHING ANYWHERE IS CHANGING in the display (either locally at the UI Document / Game Object / Panel level or even Globally at the application level - no visual changes at all). It is a completely static display at that time.

Can you throttle down the rendering rate of the UI Toolkit / Game Object / Panel / Project (even right down to zero) without changing `Application.targetFrameRate`?

I can throttle `Application.targetFrameRate` down pretty low to around 15 fps when no visual changes are happening and bump it back up when more is happening. But I can't throttle it down further or I won't catch update events efficiently like new clicks/releases.

On the other hand, when I know there is no visual change, I could throttle the RENDERING rate down to zero hypothetically, since no new display rendering needs to occur.

Is there any way to do this? Or does it not make sense? I don't know how UI Toolkit or Unity renders the final app visual output.

***Background Questions:***

If you make a non-changing visual element based display and then leave it idling on a screen at 120 fps:

- What is updating every frame?
- Is it re-calculating the flexing for the panel every frame?
- Is it re-drawing all the elements every frame?
- Is it constantly checking all its fields every frame fps for updates and only re-drawing if one is found?

If such a code can be done to throttle rendering without throttling the app's global rate, a test example to illustrate would be say hypothetically:

```
VisualElement ve;
float frameRate = 120;

void Awake(){
   Application.targetFrameRate = frameRate;
   ve = new VisualElement();
   GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement.Add(ve);
   StartCoroutine(updateTest());
}

IEnumerator updateTest(){

   //request a random change to appearance of visual element on screen at frame rate
   ve.style.Color =  new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1));
   ve.style.width = ve.style.height =  UnityEngine.Random.Range(2,500);

   Debug.Log(1/Time.deltaTime); // should continue to output around frameRate

   yield return null;
}

void Update(){
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
   runFunctionToThrottleRendering(); //hypothetical function that would then throttle the rendering pipeline
}
```

Is there any way to command in the panel or Unity background code that would allow me to turn on/off updates or change the rate of updates to the Panel/UI Document/rendering pipeline from the UI Toolkit so you would no longer see the random changes (even while the commands continue in the background at the rate of `Update()`)?

ie. So if I were to trigger this command, the `updateTest()` can keep running at 120 fps but it will no longer render any new changes to the visual output and the display will remain static?

(Obviously I could throttle or turn on/off the coroutine's function internally but this is not what I'm asking - the code is just a hypothetical illustrative example.)

There are long periods when someone might be reading or looking at an unchanging screen in an app, and as I said, I can throttle the `Application.targetFrameRate` pretty low in those cases. But ideally, I could even shut off any visual updates happening to the screen at all (or background checks inside the UI Toolkit code) since I know absolutely none need to occur at those times.

I am interested even in methods I would have to access by Reflection. I don't mind. I would also be interested in methods that can do it just for UI toolkit or a panel or even globally for all of Unity.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you? [How to re-render the scene only when something changes in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/197221/39518)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that only handles camera output rendering. I am referring to the UI Toolkit (which doesn't work through cameras but rather "panels"). As you said over there perhaps there is no easy way to do what I am wondering about. Throttling down to 15 fps as I am doing now is decent enough. Thanks.